# What is the difference in tags

Tags: html, video

Here are 3 ways to write the same thing. Is there any advantage to writing HTML one way over another? I know certain forms are more strict than others, but uncertain if that has anything to do with this.

```
<video controls src=video.mp4>

<video controls>
<source src="video.mp4">

<video controls src="video.mp4"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

All these are basically not correct. If they *do* work, it's due to the particular browsers error tolerance.

The correct way is to use an opening and closing tag with one or several `source` tags in between which offer different file formats of the same video content. In addition, it's also usual to add a test message for browsers which can't handle that code:

```
<video controls>
   <source src="my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4;">
   <source src="my_video.ogv" type="video/ogg;">
   <p>Your browser does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
```